# Put border on multiple sheets using Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I have a Google Spreadsheet with about 20 sheet to create reports using some importrange functions. I am trying to get this script to work by looking through all the sheets on edit and putting a border around any cell that has contents but it does not seems to be working.

```
function onEdit(e){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheets = ss.getSheets();

var numSheets = ss.getNumSheets(); // count of sheets

// for every sheet
for( var s = 0; s < numSheets ; s++ ) { 
var sheet = sheets[s]; // passes an individual sheet object to var sheet
//Add borders to non-empty 
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();
//set border
 range.setBorder(false, false, false, false, false, false);
  var values = range.getValues();
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
     for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
       if (values[i][j] !== "") {
         range.getCell(i + 1, j + 1).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true,    true);
       }
     }
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest trying this function instead:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var ss  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var range = ss.getDataRange();

  var maxCol = range.getLastColumn();
  var maxRow = range.getLastRow();

  for (var i=0; i<maxRow; i++)
  {
    for (var j=0; j<maxCol; j++)
    {
      if(!ss.getRange(i+1, j+1).isBlank()) //Check whether the cell is blank
      {
        ss.getRange(i+1, j+1).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Reason being, the function you wrote runs everytime you make an edit to any of the sheets and iterates through all sheets. That is if you edit cell A14 on Sheet1, it will iterate through all 20 sheets checking the borders of the entire range for all sheets. Whereas, they might already have borders from it's previous run and nothing has changed in the other 19 sheets. This way, it iterates through the borders of the current sheet as soon as an edit is made on the sheet. However, I would like to bring 2 point for you to note with the current function:

- onEdit only accepts user input as an "Edit".
- Your sheet might end up looking something like this
  [image]

Depending on what kind of data you're representing, this might or might not be what you desire. However, if I simplified the function a little more and used the following one:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var ss  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var range = ss.getDataRange();
  range.setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true);
}
```

I get the following sheet, with a much simpler and faster code:
[image]

The first scenario does exactly what your description desires, by adding a border to every cell that has data. However, the second one will only add borders to the extent of your data table in respect of maximum row and column. Hope this helps!

Comment: This works for one sheet but I want to traverse multiple sheets. Basically the sheets are collecting data from a form so whenever a form is submitted, depending on the criteria for each sheet it does an import range.

Comment: Well, one thing to remember here is that [onEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) only accepts user input as a "change". Hence, it might not add the borders when the script adds data to the sheet. However, you can use `onOpen()` function instead which would add borders to all sheets soon as you open them. Another option might be use a time driven trigger. Like add borders to the sheets after every hour or two or at midnight etc.

Comment: However, if you do want to parse through all sheets adding borders soon as the user submits the form, I would suggest change the name of the first function I mentioned above to something else like `myFunction` and set an [onFormSubmit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onformsubmit) trigger to run `myFunction` every time user submits a response.